# Playing AES-encrypted HLS streams using separate AES key

Tags: android, aes, android-mediaplayer

I have an AES-encrypted HLS stream that I am passing into Android's MediaPlayer. Normally, the AES key is passed in as part of the stream (using #EXT-X-KEY). However, my client wants to provide the key separately. Would it be possible to pass the AES key to the MediaPlayer separately, or would I need to implement my own version of MediaPlayer in order to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

As it states in the [spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-19#section-4.3.2.4)

> URI
>
> The value is a quoted-string containing a URI that specifies how
> to obtain the key.  This attribute is REQUIRED unless the METHOD
> is NONE.

You could get the key externally and have an echo server that takes the key in base64 to return the decoded key.